# How to use \lIf and \lFor in one line for algorithm2e?

Tags: line-breaking, algorithm2e

I'm using algorithm2e and am familiar with \lIf and \lFor to have no extra lines.  But when I use both of them together, an extra blank line gets inserted.  Is there a way to avoid that line?  MWE below.

```
\usepackage[ruled,vlined,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\DontPrintSemicolon
\SetKw{KwBreak}{break}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[ht]
\caption{BWT::decoding($C$, $S$)}
\lFor{$j=0$ to $n-1$}{\lIf{$C[j]=\$$}{\KwBreak}}
Do some other stuff
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try using \lFor*

Comment: Awsome!  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since version 5.1 of [`algorithm2e`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) it provides `l`-commands; from the change log/release notes in the [`algorithm2e` documentation](//texdoc.net/pkg/algorithm2e):

> `l` commands (the ones as `\lIf`) can now be used with a
> star. If done, no end of line are done, so you can enclose
> `l` command into another one. For example, you can write:
> `\lForEach{$i$}{\lIf*{foo}{bar}}`.
> Note that when you use a star, side comments are not allowed.

So, either `\lFor*{.}{\lIf{..}{...}}` or `\lFor{.}{\lIf*{..}{...}}` would work.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ruled,vlined,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}

\DontPrintSemicolon
\SetKw{KwBreak}{break}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[ht]
  \caption{BWT::decoding($C$, $S$)}
  \lFor*{$j = 0$ to $n - 1$}{\lIf{$C[j] = \$$}{\KwBreak}}
  \lFor{$j = 0$ to $n - 1$}{\lIf*{$C[j] = \$$}{\KwBreak}}
  Do some other stuff
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```